# How to align content using form inline?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would like to align add files to the right and the other content to the left, every component of the form must be one the same line. Unfortunately I'm not able to align the first three form-group on the left, and the last one on the right, check:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline">

    <div class="form-group mr-2">
        <select id="attachmentFilter" class="form-control">
            <option><?= lang('media.all_media') ?></option>
            <option value="image"><?= lang('media.images') ?></option>
            <option value="archives"><?= lang('media.archives') ?></option>
            <option value="detached"><?= lang('media.detached') ?></option>
            <option value="mine"><?= lang('media.mine') ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mr-2">
        <select id="dates" class="form-control">
            <option value="0"><?= lang('media.all_dates') ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mr-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            Filter
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mr-2">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseDropzone" role="button">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add files
        </a>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check below code

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline">

    <div class="form-group mr-2">
        <select id="attachmentFilter" class="form-control">
            <option><?= lang('media.all_media') ?></option>
            <option value="image"><?= lang('media.images') ?></option>
            <option value="archives"><?= lang('media.archives') ?></option>
            <option value="detached"><?= lang('media.detached') ?></option>
            <option value="mine"><?= lang('media.mine') ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mr-2">
        <select id="dates" class="form-control">
            <option value="0"><?= lang('media.all_dates') ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mr-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            Filter
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mr-2 ml-auto">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseDropzone" role="button">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add files
        </a>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using rows then give inner divs col-6:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6>
       # Put left contents here....
    </div>
    <div class="col-6>
       # Put right contents here...
    </div>
</div>
```